# Aggregate query error in apex

Tags: apex

```
List<OrderSummary> os  = [SELECT Id, TotalTaxAmount,BillingState, BillingCity,BillingStreet,BillingCountry,BillingPostalCode,GrandTotalAmount,BillingPhoneNumber,
                       (SELECT TotalTaxAmount, ProductCode, Quantity, GrossUnitPrice, Status, UnitPrice, TotalPrice, QuantityCanceled, QuantityReturned, QuantityOrdered 
                         FROM OrderItemSummaries WHERE Type = 'ABC' ORDER BY Name),
                       (SELECT Id, Type, Status, FulfillmentOrderNumber, TotalDeliveryAmount, TotalDeliveryAdjustAmount, FulfilledToPhone, FulfilledToEmailAddress, FulfilledToState, FulfilledToCity, FulfilledToStreet, FulfilledToCountry, FulfilledToPostalCode, DeliveryMethod.ReferenceNumber, TotalTaxAmount, GrandTotalAmount, FulfilledToName 
                         FROM FulfillmentOrders),
                       (SELECT Type, LastPaymentGatewayLog.PaymentGatewayId 
                         FROM OrderPaymentSummaries),
                       (SELECT GiftMessage, OrderSummaryId, DeliverToName, EmailAddress 
                         FROM OrderDeliveryGroupSummaries),
                       (SELECT Id, TrackingNumber, Status 
                         FROM Shipments)
                       FROM OrderSummary WHERE Id = :orderSummaryId];
```

"I am facing an issue while processing multiple records in Apex. I have a query that retrieves data from several related objects, and the aggregate results exceed the 'Aggregate Query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop' limit. The number of records in each query result varies:

OrderSummary: 1 Record

FulfillmentOrder: 600 records

OrderItemSummary: 1600 records

OrderDeliveryGroupSummary: 600 records

Shipment: 500 records

I am using this data to prepare a JSON request in a function. How can I handle this large amount of data without encountering the mentioned error? Additionally, if I separate the queries and use a FOR loop, how can I avoid hitting the APEX CPU limit exception?

Comment: you could remove the subqueries 1x1 until you are under the limit and then for the removed ones, query those directly using the OrderSummaryId field.

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't the query itself, the issue is with the code you're using to process the results.
You run into this error because of how Salesforce handles queries. Every ~200 records, Salesforce makes an internal call to `queryMore()`, and Salesforce doesn't really let us do that for nested queries.

So things like `List<Child_Record__c> childRecs = SomeObject.ChildRecords;` is not safe. It'll generally work if you have fewer than 200 child records (for a given child SObject type) for a given parent record, but the safe solution here is to use nested loops (and nested loops are *not inherently evil*).

e.g.

```java
List<Opportunity> allOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
List<Contact> allContacts = new List<Contact>();

for(Account myAccount : [SELECT  (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities), ... FROM Account ...]) {
    // A nested loop is the only safe way to get at child records
    // Even calling something like myAccount.Opportunities.size() is unsafe
    for(Opportunity opp : myAccount.Opportunities) {
        allOpps.add(opp);
    }

    // One nested loop for each child object you need to process
    for(Contact cont : myAccount.Contacts) {
        allContacts.add(cont);
    }
}
```

3,301 records total isn't really that large (don't get me wrong, it's not a small data volume given the governor limits), so you shouldn't really need to worry about the CPU limit here (nor query rows). If anything, the heap space consumed might be the most prominent concern.

Using nested loops should help mitigate that (because the data stored in the heap can be freed after a loop has finished working through one chunk of the data). Though if you're storing the records in a collection outside of the loop like I did in my example, the heap-space benefit of using "soql for loops" (where the query is part of the `for()` statement itself) disappears.